# Max min zoom in different devices Xcode using Swift

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uiscrollview, zooming

I've got a problem with my UIScrollView when i'm testing my app on different devices. I've set the max and min zoom scale correct on the Iphone 6 device, but when I try it out on the Iphone 6 plus, or Iphone 5, I can't figure out how to see my whole image when i'm zooming without letting it bounce back to place again. I really need some help to make it able to set different zoom scales for different devices. Please help! Thanks :)

Heres my scrollview and imageview zoom scale code:

```
import UIKit

class DetailViewController: UIViewController, UIScrollViewDelegate {




@IBOutlet weak var scrollView: UIScrollView!
@IBOutlet weak var myDetailedImageView: UIImageView!


var myDetailedImageName: String?
var nameString: String?


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()



    func minscale () {

    }

    scrollView.minimumZoomScale = 0.15
    scrollView.maximumZoomScale = 2.0
    scrollView.delegate = self

    self.myDetailedImageView.image = UIImage(named: myDetailedImageName!)

}


func viewForZoomingInScrollView(scrollView: UIScrollView) -> UIView? {



    return myDetailedImageView
}


// Do any additional setup after loading the view.


override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


/*
// MARK: - Navigation

// In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little        preparation before navigation
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
// Get the new view controller using segue.destinationViewController.
// Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
}
*/

}
```

Here's an example of how it looks like on the Iphone 5:

[image]

And here's an example of how it should look like, on the Iphone 6:
[image]